# RSpec stubs & mocks on related (belongs_to) relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2

I'm trying to get my head around RSpec's incredibly confusing, at least initially, syntax by trying to expand on the default specs that are generated with Rails 3 scaffolding...

I have associated models...very simply:

```
#clown.rb
class Clown < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rabbits
end

#rabbit.rb
class Rabbit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :clown
end
```

but I'm having trouble with rabbits_controller.spec.rb. In that the specs fail when I reference, say, clown.**name** in one of rabbit's views. the stupid simple app works as expected but the specs fail because I haven't stubbed (or mocked?) the clown to respond correctly from the rabbit (or at least that's what I think is happening)?!? How should I be adding a stub (or mocking the clown that the rabbit is associate to?).

existing:

```
   #rabbits.controller.spec.rb
    require 'spec_helper'

    describe RabbitsController do

      def mock_rabbit(stubs={})
        (@mock_rabbit ||= mock_model(Rabbit).as_null_object).tap do |rabbit|
          rabbit.stub(stubs) unless stubs.empty?
        end
      end

      describe "GET index" do
        it "assigns all rabbits as @rabbits" do
          Rabbit.stub(:all) { [mock_rabbit] }
          get :index
          assigns(:rabbits).should eq([mock_rabbit])
        end
      end

  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO (and there are other points of view) this isn't a mocking or stubbing situation.  Mocks and stubs are great for external dependencies (think web service), but this is internal to your application.  What you want is something like factory_girl, which will let you create test data without the headaches of something like fixtures or trying to mock out every dependent relationship, which quickly becomes monotonous.  factory_girl has great documentation, but briefly here's what your factories might look like:

```
Factory.define(:clown) do |f|
  f.rabbits{|c| [c.assocation(:rabbit)]}
  f.name "Pierrot"
end

Factory.define(:rabbit) do |f|
  f.association :clown
end
```

You'd then use them in your test like so:

```
describe RabbitsController do 
  describe "GET index" do 
    it "assigns rabbits" do
      @rabbit = Factory(:rabbit)
      get :index
      assigns[:rabbits].should == [@rabbit]      
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: well, then this gets more confusing to someone learning.. why would the Rails3/RSpec template include the `mock_rabbit` block as a default? Just to confuse the hell out of people like me? I'm finding that the more I learn about Rails the less I actually know...

Comment: I have no idea :) Maybe they have some tricks I don't know, but as someone who tests religiously i've found life much easier with factories for my internal dependencies.  For awhile there were a lot of people clamoring about keeping your tests independent of a database connection, but I think over time that's mellowed out as its kind of a PITA and your tests end up becoming more about jumping through hoops than focusing on application testing.